# I am getting dataset error in artificial intelligence project

Tags: python, scikit-learn

CODE:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Veri setini yükle
data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/erdi/Desktop/son20yil/STSL_yeni.csv')
print(data)

# Tahmin yapılacak maçın takım adlarını belirle
takim1_adi = "BESIKTAS"
takim2_adi = "FENERBAHCE"

# Tahmin yapılacak maçın özelliklerini belirle
takim1 = data[data['TakimAdi'] == takim1_adi]
takim1_ozellikler = takim1[['MacSayisi', 'AtGol', 'YeGol', 'Galibiyet', 'Beraberlik', 'Maglubiyet']]

takim2 = data[data['TakimAdi'] == takim2_adi]
takim2_ozellikler = takim2[['MacSayisi', 'AtGol', 'YeGol', 'Galibiyet', 'Beraberlik', 'Maglubiyet']]

tahmin_ozellikler = pd.concat([takim1_ozellikler, takim2_ozellikler], axis=1).values

# Özellikler ve hedef değişkeni ayır
features = data.drop(['Puan', 'TakimAdi'], axis=1)
target = data['Puan']

# Eğitim ve test veri setlerini bölelim
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, target, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

# Çoklu lineer regresyon modelini oluştur
model = LinearRegression()

# Modeli eğit
model.fit(X_train, y_train)


# Tahmin yap
tahmin_skor = model.predict(tahmin_ozellikler)

print("Tahmin edilen skor:", tahmin_skor)
```

DATA SET:

[image: img]

I want to perform a match score analysis based on the number of matches, goals scored, goals conceded, wins, draws, and losses of teams in the dataset using the k-nearest neighbors algorithm.

The error I received:

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

Comment: Not sure we can help you with data we can't see that probably has issues. Data cleaning is an important part of training.

Comment: Please don't paste the image of data, possibly share\paste dataset itself possibly.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you have `nans` values in your data, thus you have to replace these `nans` with some values.

A simple method is to use an imputer.

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imp = SimpleImputer()
train_data_imputed = imp.fit_transform(train_data)
# in testing
test_data_imputed = imp.transform(test_data)
```

You can check https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html for more variants.